# std::rotate return value in gcc 4.9

Tags: algorithm, gcc, c++11, gcc4.9

Is it bug, that `std::rotate` function have `void` return value type in **GCC** 4.9 even if I specify `-std=gnu++1y` flag? As it pointed [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate) there should be meaningfull (for some applications) return value.

Comment: How do you call `std::rotate`? There're two versions one returns `void` and the other an `iterator`.

Comment: Please explain what do you imply when you ask me about "how I call"? Do you know, that expected result type is not involved in overloading resolution?

Comment: There is only the version. Where you seen two ones?

Comment: Pre C++11 and post C++11.

Comment: @40two OK, but in particular translation unit after the preprocessing step only one is reachable anyways. Which one is depend on compiler flags.

Comment: +1 You're right, I think it's not implemented yet. Thus, it is a bug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- It looks like `std::rotate` in gcc doesn't conform to the C++11 standard (i.e., it's not implemented yet).
- I searched [GCC Bugzilla](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58357) and it seems that the bug is already reported since version 4.8.1 and currently being unassigned with status new.
- Thus, is a bug. Well spotted you should report it.

Comment: WRT third clause, I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Can you explain, why this "bug" (so little at my mind: just changing two lines of code) is not fixed at the moment? Very interesting situation in light of usefulness of the **libstdc++**.

Comment: @Orient I agree with you, but for this you'll have to ask the GCC developers.